# Chrome Launching Issue - Appium + Robot Framework

Tags: google-chrome, appium, robotframework

I'm just beginner for appium + Robot Framework.
Below is my code to invoke chrome browser in android device/emulator and launch a website. When  run this in robot framework + appium , chrome browser launched with data:, as in the address bar and the browser gets closed and relaunched again and again.

```
Open Application http://localhost:4723/wd/hub platformName=Android platformVersion=6.0.0 deviceName=192.168.188.101:5555 appPackage=com.android.chrome appActivity=org.chromium.chrome.browser.ChromeTabbedActivity
Close All Application
```

[Video recording - Chrome issue](https://app.hyfy.io/v/ab6mdKWXQi/)

Can you please help me to overcome this issue

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you to get started? https://github.com/Atihinen/robotframework-appium-example

Comment: Thanks @joonasj . I have problem only with running the cases with chrome browser in the android devices. I'm successful in  running test cases with appium against android application